# pm2 --update-env option seems not working

Tags: node.js, pm2

I launched my node app by using ecosystem.config.js like this.

`pm2 start ecosystem.config.js`

And my ecosystem.config.js is here.

```
module.exports = {
  /**
  * Application configuration section
  * http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/
  */
  apps : [
    // First application
    {
      name      : "API",
      script    : "./app/index.js",
      env: {
        COMMON_VARIABLE: "true"
      },
      env_production : {
        NODE_ENV: "production"
      }
    },
  ],

  /**
  * Deployment section
  * http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/deployment/
  */
  deploy : {
    production : {
      user : "node",
      host : "212.83.163.1",
      ref  : "origin/master",
      repo : "git@github.com:repo.git",
      path : "/var/www/production",
      "post-deploy" : "npm install && pm2 startOrRestart ecosystem.json --env production"
    },
    dev : {
      user : "node",
      host : "212.83.163.1",
      ref  : "origin/master",
      repo : "git@github.com:repo.git",
      path : "/var/www/development",
      "post-deploy" : "npm install && pm2 startOrRestart ecosystem.json --env dev",
      env  : {
        NODE_ENV: "dev"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then I tried to change the config file for watching mode on. I read [this document](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/#updating-configurations-of-already-running-applications) so, I added `watch: true` attribute, then I tried `pm2 restart ecosystem.config.js --update-env` for applying changed config.

The app is restarted and attribute seems to be changed, because when I try `pm2 list` the watching is enabled. But my app is not restarted after change my code.

So, I just tried `pm2 delete 0`, `pm2 start ecosystem.config.js` then It's working well.

Why does `--update-env` options not working? What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The only reliable ways I've found to update a pm2 app config is either `pm2 kill` to stop the daemon, or `pm2 delete <id|name> && pm2 start ecosystem.config.js` for an individual app (as @hshan mentioned).

This issue claims it was fixed in 2014, but the comments there, plus the string of other questions/issues I found would seem to indicate otherwise:
https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/528

Update: Ongoing discussion here as well: https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/3192

Comment: After about a half hour of stackoverflow, this did it for me... `pm2 kill` did nothing, `pm2 delete` and then `pm2 start ecosystem.config.js` was the way to go!

Comment: #only this helps me
pm2 restart ecosystem.config.js --update-env --env production

Comment: You are a savior

Comment: Hey, for me `pm2 stop all`, then `pkill pm2` and then start it again worked out. However, for some reason, when I restart the service, it still shows me the purple message: `Use --update-env to update environment variables`

Comment: Looks like `pm2 kill` workaround works, but it has to be done forever every time after environment variables were updated for the first time ever. Otherwise it keeps loading old variables when just reloading ecosystem file.

Answer (score 13):

`pm2 restart <pid> --update-env` worked for me as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55420334/8203074) answer

Answer (score 3):

```
pm2 restart ecosystem.config.js --env production
```

I don't need --update-env but I do need to specify the env again on restart

Another option that I found was specifying the var on the cmd line:

```
MY_VAR=1234 pm2 restart ecosystem.config.js
```

Interestingly, this keeps it in the previous env, but the cmd line var will overwrite the values you have in your ecosystem.config.js for the same var.

However

```
MY_VAR=1234 pm2 restart ecosystem.config.js --env production
```

WILL overwrite the cmd line MY_VAR if you have one defined in your ecosystem for production.

Comment: PM2][WARN] Applications  not running, starting...
[PM2][ERROR] Error: No script path - aborting

Answer (score 1):

This update error happend when it tried to write to Z:\ drive

However, there is no Z:\ drive in my Windows OS machine

Below helped fix the issue:

1 . Add user environment variable as below:

```
PM2_HOME=%USERPROFILE%\.pm2
```

2 . Then kill pm2 daemon once

```
pm2 kill
```

Now `pm2 update` works fine.

Comment: This worked very well on my linux server, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

One reason may also be like.

suppose you have 2 repo.
`/repo-backend-1`
`/repo-backend-2`

In first repo, there is a env file for example.
`S3_SECRET=efgh`

In second repo, there is a env file for example.
`S3_SECRET=abcd`

And you are starting repo-1 by pm2.
So first it would take `S3_SECRET=efgh`.
Then you are starting the second repo-2 by pm2.
So then it would take `S3_SECRET=abcd`.

So in the first repo, the env variable will be abcd and the credentials are mismatched.

So make sure that both env variable are same.