# Environment Variables not loading to process.env in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, environment-variables

I'm building out a nodejs api and have setup the `dotenv` package as a dev dependency to load the variables to `process.env` on developer's local machines.

Note that when I log in I use `sudo -i` to operate as `root`.

My intent is that during deployment, environment variables would be set in my Ubuntu host under `/etc/environment`, loaded directly in to the process, and then the app would just run for that configuration.

To do this, I have a line at the start of `server.js`:

```
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    logger.info("Loading dotenv for development environment")
    require('dotenv').config();
}
```

And developers will be instructed to add an environment variable to their system for `NODE_ENV`.

Now, in my Ubuntu EC2 instance I've setup the `/etc/environment` to have the environment variables I want (note that NODE_ENV being 'dev' here is just to avoid running dotenv):

```
PORT=MYPORT
NODE_ENV=dev
APP_SECRET_KEY='MYSECRET'
APP_DATABASE_LOGIN=MYLOGIN
APP_DATABASE_PASSWORD='MYPASS'
APP_DATABASE_HOST=MYHOST
APP_DATABASE_NAME=MYDB
APP_DATABASE_PORT=MYDBPORT
```

And when I reboot and run `printenv` they are all populated per the file.

I have setup `pm2` to run my application directly from `server.js` without any additional configuration because as I understand it, `process.env` is populated automatically from environment variables.

However, when I log the values from process.env, I just get null for everything:

```
logger.info({
    connectionConfig: {
        host: process.env.APP_DATABASE_HOST
        , login: process.env.APP_DATABASE_LOGIN
        , port: process.env.APP_DATABASE_PORT
        , databaseName: process.env.APP_DATABASE_NAME
    }
});
```

Is there something wrong with the configuration as-is here?

Note: Per the answer below, I had mistakenly setup my environment variables AFTER starting pm2, and as such pm2 caching was missing them

Comment: what happens if you run it without `pm2`?

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande When I run `npm start` directly it loads the environment variables correctly but since PM2 is running and using the port already, it fails

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The issue is that `pm2` caches the environment variables.

You have to do:

```sh
# all apps
pm2 restart all --update-env
# specific app
pm2 restart {pid} --update-env
```

If for some reason that doesn't work, the documented way is:

```
pm2 reload ecosystem.json --update-env
```

You can read more in [here](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/environment/):

Comment: Hi Marcos - thanks for this. Your original question made me investigate and I came to the same conclusion. However, the fix for me was to execute `pm2 restart --update-env all`. Can you put this as the first line of your answer so I can accept?

Comment: Added that line too.

Comment: I had mistakenly setup my environment variables AFTER starting pm2 earlier in the process and didn't know about the caching - thanks again!

Answer (score 5):

I 've gone through the same problem it's because of the integrated terminal in visual studio and visual studio code it seems like they don't have access to any of these variables unless you run the editor in Admin mode.so to solve this problem you just need to **start your editor in Amin mode**

Answer (score 3):

**Make sure you have this code in app.js file**

```
> const path = require('path');  require('dotenv').config({ path:
> path.join(__dirname, '.env') });
```